# Wrapping text in R plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need to wrap the text in this plot. Anyone knows how?

I already tried using check_overlap but the labels are very separated from each other.

```
    ex<-data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(1.732050808, 1.732050808, 1.732050808, 1.732050808, 0.866025404, 0.866025404, 0.866025404, 0.866025404, 0.866025404, 0.866025404
), z="Very very very very very very very very very very long text")

ggplot(ex,mapping = aes(x,y, label = (z)))+
  geom_text(size=2, check_overlap = F)+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi! I just have 3 columns, the first two are the plot points (x,y) the third one is the long label (z)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: added to the question! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ggrepel` package to avoid overlapping issues. You just need to replace `geom_text` by `geom_text_repel` and remove the argument `check_overlap`. For instance:

```
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(ex,mapping = aes(x,y, label = (z)))+
  geom_text_repel(size=2)+
  geom_point()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Actually I did try it but it didn't work given the amount of points (example above)

Comment: you could play around the font size, orientation and segment.size, etc. If the number of data points is huge you won't be able of accommodating them in the plot. For that case, there is not much point adding the text to the plot. You could use ggplotly that displays info of the dot hovering over a data point